# Ошибка в виртуальном окружении

Tags: python, virtualenv

Есть скрипт на VDS, в первой строке:

```
import uvicorn
```

Запускаю через:

```
python script.py
```

Выходит ошибка:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'uvicorn'
```

При этом виртуальное окружение активно и в списке установленных модулей, через:

```
sudo pip freeze
```

Есть uvicorn:

> uvicorn==0.21.0

Собственно сам вопрос: почему виртуальное окружение не видит **uvicorn**?

UPD:

1. В папке проекта виртуальное окружение в папке **myprojectenv**
2. Запуск  ВО делаю через : **source myprojectenv/bin/activate** (Находяст в папке проекта)
3. После активации, если запустить Python через:

```
python
```

И там импортировать uvicorn, то будет та же ошибка:

```
Python 3.9.16 (main, Dec  7 2022, 01:11:58)
[GCC 7.5.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import uvicorn
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'uvicorn'
```

Comment: если запустить не скрипт, а uvicorn на прямую, например запросить доку `uvicorn --help`, сработает?

Comment: @Dmitry, да - указывает документацию, какие опции можно использовать

Comment: а если зайти в интерпетатор python и попробовать импортировать? `import uvicorn`

Comment: А питон точно тот запускается, в который установлен `uvicorn`? Для начала `python -V` посмотрите - та ли версия запускается. Ну и можно попробовать полный путь к питону указать. И проверить в путях какой указан.

Comment: @Dmitry, та же ошибка.

Comment: следовательно, нет связи интерпретатора python и виртуального окружения. Проверьте, что вам CrazyElf подсказывает